# How to refer Apex Class output in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I have a LWC component which should show list of topic and subtopic in **experience cloud** (community cloud), my apex class might be correct which queries all the related topic and stores in a variable, but I do not know how to use it under LWC

Could you please help me to figure it out  what I am missing? I am sure I have to add some code under .js file but not sure what, maybe @wire/ import method...

.html

```
    <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open class="slds-m-around_medium" active-section-name={activeSections}>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label={topicList}>
            <p>
                Related Article 1 - for Payment & Deliveries   <br/>                      
                Related Article 2- for Payment & Deliveries   <br/>
                .....  {recordId} <br/> 

                
                
            </p>
            <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://elopage.my.site.com/helpcenter/s/topic/{recordId}"  
                label="Related Article 1 - for Payment & Deliveries " target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>
            <p><lightning-formatted-url value="https://elopage.my.site.com/helpcenter/s/topic/{recordId}"  
                label="Related Article 2 - for Payment & Deliveries " target="_blank" ></lightning-formatted-url></p>    

        </lightning-accordion-section>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="B" label="Notes On End Customer Support">
            <p>
                Testing 4<br/>
                Testing 5<br/>
                Testing 6<br/>

            </p>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
        <lightning-accordion-section name="C" label="Contact The Seller">
            <p>
                Testing 7<br/>
                Testing 8<br/>
                Testing 9<br/>

            </p>
        </lightning-accordion-section>
    </lightning-accordion>
</lightning-card>
```

.js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import TOPIC_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Topic.Name';


const fields = [TOPIC_NAME];

export default class CustomAccordionLWC extends LightningElement {



// handling Topic header (parent)    
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    topic;

    get name() {
        return getFieldValue(this.topic.data, TOPIC_NAME);
    }

 


// handling the button actions
    activeSections = [];

    expandAll() {

        this.activeSections = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ];

    }

    collapseAll() {

        this.activeSections = [];
 
    }

}
```

.cls

```
public with sharing class CustomAccordionLWC{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ConnectApi.Topic> getNavigationTopics(){
    string commId = [Select Id from Network where Name = 'Payer Help Center'].Id;    
    ConnectApi.ManagedTopicCollection topics = ConnectApi.ManagedTopics.getManagedTopics(commId);
    for (ConnectApi.ManagedTopic managedTopic : topics.managedTopics) {
        System.debug('###managedTopic.topic.name = ' + ((ConnectApi.Topic)managedTopic.topic).name);
    
        Set<String> topicNames = new Set<String>();
        for (ConnectApi.ManagedTopic childManagedTopic : managedTopic.children) {
            topicNames.add(((ConnectApi.Topic)childManagedTopic.topic).name + '\n');
        }
    
        System.debug('### childTopicNames:\n' + String.join(topicNames, '\n'));
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is Topic a field in ConnectApi object?

Comment: Topic is an object in Salesforce, where we could categorize in experience cloud - and each topic can have a sub-topic assigned, I exactly need an accordion which displays subtopic when I open the parent topic. I cannot find a data model for that but here is the documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_topic.htm

Syntax referred in class - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedTopics_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ManagedTopics_getManagedTopics_3

Comment: It says I need 20 reputation to start the chat :/

Comment: Oops I am sorry, I was not aware of that requirement

Comment: If that is okay for you, can we have a Gmeet? or any other medium where you could help, please?

Comment: I am not sure if it is allowed in the community, but anyways if you invite I will join

Comment: Can you please write me on dharmin.kansara@elopage.com - we can schedule something and also would be appropriate method to contact. I will wait for it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

1. [@wire method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method)
2. [Imperative apex method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative)

**1. Imperative Method**
Here I have listed an example, of how to use imperative apex method,

You first have to deploy your apex code to your org and then import in your .js file like this:

```
import getNavigationTopics from '@salesforce/apex/CustomAccordionLWC.getNavigationTopics';
export default class CustomAccordionLWC extends LightningElement {


navigationTopics; // just setting a variable to store the output from apex method, you can name it whatever you want.


connectedCallback(){
    this.getNavigationTopics(); //calling it in connectedCallback, since the apex class, takes no input as parameters, you can of course choose to call it wherever you want.

}
getNavigationTopics(){
    getNavigationTopics().then(results => {
        this.navigationTopics = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
        console.log('navigationTopics -->', this.navigationTopics);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error occured-->',error);
    })
}
}
```

I wrote the a function for it because, so that you can call the function once whenever you want to invoke the apex code.

**2. Using @wire method**
Based on the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method). If you would like to use the @wire method, you must **always** add (cacheable=true) on your @AuraEnabled methods, so your apex method would be @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)

Since your apex code takes no parameter you can just do this:

```
import getNavigationTopics from '@salesforce/apex/CustomAccordionLWC.getNavigationTopics';
export default class CustomAccordionLWC extends LightningElement {


@wire(getNavigationTopics) navigationTopics;
//you can of course call the navigationTopics above to whatever you want.
}
```

Since your apex method is not taking in any parameter you don't have to pass in any parameters.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

> In your apex getNavigationTopics method, you have to include a return
> statement. What is returned from the method is what will be received
> in the LWC.

Also as a best practice please, use try and catch block for your apex methods, in that way you can catch and throw an exception just in case, which can be used when there's an error in the apex method, we can use console.log (in javascript), to show the error and understand the error.

Comment: Useful!

I have created an apex class, as you mentioned that I need to return it. I have an error in return...

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Apex_Code_Development&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=9065d000000Xcj3AAC

A test class would also be appreciable for this above use case!